# Dynamic html onClick

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am playing around with the HTML service of GAS.
It has been working fine (more or less). But I hit a wall now.
I want the script (inside the html file) to create some html on when called.
In particular a few  tags. 
However, I want those tags to have onClick handlers (which will edit the div element).
Now the problem is that the onClick should depend on certain properties and I can not 
pre-create those objects, they have to be made pragmatically and for some reason when I add a 
onClick="someFunction(elementID)" after the new code has been added to the old one the click handler disappears.
(it works tho if the handler function has no parameters)

```
eg.
var div="<div id=\"box"+count+"\" class=\"square\" insert></div>";

if(something)

div=div.replace("insert", "onclick=\"myFunction(box"+count+"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional and documented: see the section called "Dynamically adding scripts or external CSS" in [the HtmlService user guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja).